# Как расшифровать емаил по хешу?

Tags: кодировка, email, хеширование

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой URL изображения
https://lardi-trans.com/dinamix/email/ZpjSo9LdHaLEexnkHiuI.png
Пример страницы
https://lardi-trans.com/user/15576162849
Подскажите, к какому URL обратиться что бы получить текстовый вариант почты.
Спасибо!

Comment: А откуда уверенность, что алгоритм детерминированный, а не просто рандомогенератор с сохранением результатов? :)

Comment: Ну где-то же есть механизм распознавания? :)

Comment: Файловая система и/или БД на сервере? :)

Comment: Конечно, не мое дело, но зачем оно? Попахивает спамерством

Comment: Но если не быть занудой, то берете cloud vision api от google и вперед